# Static variable storage location

Tags: c

If we create a static variable in global and local with  same name, means code is getting compiled. But i expected that it will give redefined error because static variables will be stored in data section memory, but we cant create two same variables in same data section. So why its getting compiled ? Actually where those two variables will be stored? please any one can you answer...

This is example code i have used,

```
static int var = 100;

void main()
{
    static int var = 200;
    printf("\n Var:%d\n", var);
}
```

Comment: The sections don't store *names*, they store *values*.

Comment: This is about variable *scope*. There are two values in memory that you've named `var`. Any reference to `var` inside of the `main` block will be to the `var` you declared inside the `main` block due to scoping rules. If you had another function in this module, say `foo()` that referenced `var` but did not declare its own, it would be referencing the `var` you declared statically at the top of the module. The compiler knows how to generate the underlying code to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Those two variable's even if stored in same section because of their same storage class specifier their scope will be different. That's how they are distinguished. We can make this also - you don't ask then if it alright or not

```
int main(void){
  int a = 1;
  {
      int a = 2;
  }
}
```

Compiler in your case will try to find the variable `var` when used and will take the one which will be found first. Inside `main` the local `var` will be considered. But in other function without declaring any variable with same name if you refer `var` it will access the global one.

And a good compiler will warn you about this `-Wshadow` option in `gcc` will tell you about this if you compile with this flag.

The idea you should clear is that - there won't be any collision or redefinition of the same variable - it is different scope on which they are defined.

Comment: Yes but a good compiler should warn you about this.